# filtering hasMany association in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm brand new to Ember and stuck on something that seems very basic.  So far in my e-commerce application, I have two models, Product, and Style; a Product has many Styles.  For each product, I want to list a subset of the styles (e.g., those that are in stock or out of stock).  Coming from a Rails background, I thought I would create a model method in Product called stockedStyles, which filters its styles and returns only those with stocked=true.  That didn't work, so I tried another approach of using a controller method, but struck out there too.

Here's the code so far: http://jsbin.com/mufumowabi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

While I would definitely like to know the best practices way of doing this, I'm also curious about other approaches people can suggest that would work but are not recommended -- and why they aren't recommended.  Especially when I'm learning something new, I like knowing all the different ways you *could* do something and then choosing the best/cleanest one.

If there's a tutorial that covers this sort of thing, please send it my way.  I couldn't find anything that does this sort of thing, even though it seems so basic.

Lastly, I've found debugging Ember to be somewhat of a black box.  For example, for the non-working code posted here, the JS console just says "error".  Tips on how I would get more information about why what I'm doing is wrong would be most appreciated as well.

TIA,
fana

Comment: For debugging and understanding your app, I highly recommend you get [Ember Inspector](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector). You can install it in Chrome, Firefox and Opera and it'll show you some of the inner workings of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. I too came from a rails background expecting similarities in the implementation only to get confused initially. Nobody is ever exaggerating when they claim Ember requires a very large learning investment, but trust me if you stick around it's totally worth it.

Real quick let's take care of a simple goof: You can assign an object property to be either Ember.computed, or function() { /***/ }.property('sdf'); You can't have both. So make that computed function either:

```
unstockedStyles: Ember.computed.filterBy('styles', 'stocked', false);
```

or

```
unstockedStyles: function() {
  return this.get('styles').filterBy('stocked', false);
}.property('styles.@each.stocked')
```

but you can't do both at once.

### Ember Models vs Rails Models

Next, the difference with Ember, coming from  rails perspective, is that models in Ember.js are intended to be extremely light, serving only as a minimal binding between the data source and the framework overall. Rails takes quite literally the opposite approach, encouraging a very heavy model object (and this is still a large source of contention in the rails community).

In ember.js, the model method helpers are intended to be placed in the **controller** objects (again, counterintuitive coming from rails). Moving that out, you'll want your models to look like this:

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  styles: DS.hasMany('style', { async: true })
});

App.Style = DS.Model.extend({
  desc: DS.attr(),
  stocked: DS.attr("boolean")
});
```

The reason for this difference from Rails is that the role of controllers in Ember.js is for "decoration" of your object, whereas in Rails its to handle incoming/outgoing data logic. For each page, you may want to render the same data in different ways. Thus, the model will remain the same, and the controller takes on the burden of encapsulating the extra fluff/computation. You can think of decoration in the same way you were taught the inheritance pattern in OO, with a slight twist:

Let's say you want to have a **Person** base class (*your Ember model*), but then you extend it to **Teacher** and **Student** subclasses (*your controllers*) in order to add an additional propertiy that may be from the same type but is not modeled in the same way. For example, Teachers and Students have a many-to-many relationship to courses, but you want to model Students as attending their courses, where Teachers are instructing them. The controller acts as a way to provide such a filter.

### ArrayController vs ObjectController

As for the controllers, computed properties for individual records should be placed in the ArrayController's associated ObjectController (we'll call it ProductController), so your controllers now look like this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

App.ProductController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    unstockedStyles: Ember.computed.filterBy('styles', 'stocked', true)
});
```

Finally, while Ember.js can automatically associate ObjectControllers with their associated ArrayController for resources defined in your router, you're loading a Product array on the IndexController, so you need to tell IndexController to use ProductController for its item behavior:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'product'
});

App.ProductController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    unstockedStyles: Ember.computed.filterBy('styles', 'stocked', true)
});
```

### Handlebars Binding

Not much here except for a small mistake: while you've enabled a computed property correctly in the proper controller, your {{#each}} loop is instead bound to the original styles array. Change it to use the new property:

```
{{#each unstockedStyles}}
  <li>
    {{desc}}, in stock: {{stocked}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

And now you're good to go!

JSBin of fixes here: http://jsbin.com/sawujorogi/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply -- very helpful.  Creating models that are light, and using controllers to decorate models, seems like a good guideline.